# What happens to the coins on a killed character?

Tags: oriflamme

In the game "Oriflamme", when killing / eliminating a character in the line that hasn't been discovered and that contains influence points on it; what happens with those coins ? Are they lost, or gained by the assassin, or retrieved by the user who stacked them there in the first place ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've not played or heard of the game before but reading the rules file [On BGG here](https://boardgamegeek.com/filepage/189059/oriflamme-english-rules) this seems to be covered in the Resolution phase example.  (and probably should be under the 'eliminate a card' rules section as well.

The example given shows that influence on an unrevealed card is discarded when the card is discarded.

> Blue's card is a Soldier which must eliminate and adjacent card. 
>   Blue chooses Red's second card, and reveals it.  Blue discards the
>   influence on it.

I think this means that no player gets the influence on the discarded card.